# Storage consumption RDS Postgres

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.4

Is there any way to see whats in the RDS storage? I have a Postgres instance on RDS. The Database in itself is very tiny, around 50MBs but the storage is showing as over 10GB is full.

What can be the reason for storage getting filled up?

Comment: Side-note: Amazon RDS creates a normal PostgreSQL instance. Use standard PostgreSQL commands to manage/examine the database.

Comment: hey John, I am already doing that but can't find anything which might have grown to fill over 9GB storage. Is there any way to find whats stored in RDS storage?